# How to make Unity Launcher show on desktop, but hide when maximized program is open?

Tags: unity, launcher

I'm looking for a way to make the Unity Launcher always show while the desktop is visible, but hide when a program like Firefox or any other maximized program is open.

The only other "solutions" I've found for this seem to involve keyboard shortcuts, which I don't want. The previously available Dodge Windows feature sounds like what I need, but unfortunately is no longer supported.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Possible, but will have to be done via custom script (shouldn't be too complex). I'll work on it , probably can post by tomorrow.

Comment: Hi M, please mention if you manage.

Comment: @JacobVlijm That's a bit old and not exactly what I'm looking for. I was hoping there's a way to accomplish this without having to use a script like that, unless it's truly is the only way.

Comment: @Master_W technically speaking, scripting is the only way, because you're trying to automate manual actions.    I agree that what Jacob linked isn't exactly  what you're asking for.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Only while a program is maximized. Otherwise, I want it to show. I don't believe the built in autohide feature works like that.

Comment: @Serg curious to what you suggest without scripting. The question does not exclude scripting.

Comment: @Serg Ah, I just meant I was hoping that there was a hidden setting somewhere, or an installable utility or something like that.

Comment: @Master_W nope, unfortunately there is no hidden settings for such a specific task.  Like I said, you're trying to automate something, and automation typically involves scripting

Comment: @Serg Ok, thank you. Would you happen to know if there's an up to date script out there that might work for me?

Comment: @Master_W uuuhm, I linked you to one, both an application specific one and a general one. Did you even look?

Comment: @Master_W  Well, there's what Jacob linked, but at least to me it seemed not exactly what you're asking. Try it out, that might suit your needs, although I was going to write one myself for your specific case.   Just curious,  would you still want me to write one or nah ?

Comment: @JacobVlijm ok, i see it

Comment: @JacobVlijm I tried out the script and it actually seems to work fairly well.

Comment: Ah cool, please mention if you run into issues. I wrote it pretty long ago, I will look into it tomorrow, see if it could use some improvement. The second one could use it anyway as I look at it now.

Comment: well, duplicate it is then

Comment: Yeah, it could use optimizing, will do tomorrow.

Comment: ....and fixed both ones...